# Switch time field for index pattern in kibana without loosing scripted fields or field formatting

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

When a time-based index is added to kibana, you have to pick the field that will act as a time field. If you want to switch from one field to another, normally I would delete the index and re-add it back. But you end up loosing scripted fields and filed formatting this way.

Is there any way to modify the existing index time field without loosing scripted fields/formatting?

It can probably be done by messing around directly with `/.kibana/index-pattern/index_pattern_name` but all my attempts with changing `timeFieldName` directly ended up dropping scripted fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way seems to update the corresponding document:

```
POST /.kibana/index-pattern/YOUR_INDEX_NAME/_update
{
    "doc": {
        "timeFieldName": "NEW_TIME_FIELD_NAME"
    }
}
```

It should preserve scripted fields.

Answer (score 13):

This is what worked for me on Kibana 7.7.0 (Elastic Cloud):

1. find the {_id} of the document whose title field corresponds to the index you want to make change

```json
GET .kibana/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "index-pattern.title": "{INDEX_PATTERN_PATTERN_VALUE}"
    }
  }
}
```

where `{INDEX_PATTERN_PATTERN_VALUE}` is the actual pattern, e.g. *"my-logs-*"*.

2. Copy the `_id` field value and change the time-field with the following code (substitute `{_id}` with the value)

```json
POST .kibana/_update/{_id}
{
  "doc": {
    "index-pattern": {
      "timeFieldName" : "{NEW_TIME_FIELD_NAME}"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to work on Kibana 5.
Instead, following is the way worked on Kibana 5.

**1. find the {id} of the document whose `title` field corresponds to the `index` you want to make change**

```
GET .kibana/index-pattern/_search
{
  "_source" : "_id",
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "title": "{NAME_OF_THE_INDEX}"
    }
  }
}
```

**2. change the timefield with following code**

```
POST /.kibana/index-pattern/{id}/_update
{
  "doc": {
    "timeFieldName" : "{NEW_TIME_FIELD_NAME}"
  } 
}
```

This worked fine with me on Kibana 5.